# Using ActiveRecord in routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I want to be able to use items from database to generate some routes. so if I add new types I don't have to manually create new routes.  I have some lower priority routes so I can't just use match ":type", :to => "items#search".  I looked for this and couldn't find anything on it so I just tried it and it worked.

```
Type.find(:all).each do |type|
    name = type.name
    match "#{name}", :to => "items#search"
end
```

My question is, is it a bad practice to do so, and if it is, why?

Thanks

EDIT:
Even thoough I already accepted an answer, I should probably add that what I was really trying to accomplish is to pass the name of the type as parameter to the route, like so:

```
Type.find(:all).each do |type|
    name = type.name
    match "#{name}", :to => "items#search", :type => name
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fine as all the different items using the same routes for item.

So all the rows in a database table called 'items' will use the same same of routes.

If you had another model, say 'price_ranges' you could have additional routes to access its methods.